# are these closures equal in metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have a question. let $M$ be a metric space. $A, B$ are its subsets such that $A{\subset}B{\subset}M$.
To my understanding, $A$ is dense in $B$ if the closure of $A$ in B!!! equals $B$. and $B$ is dense in M, if the closure of $B$ in $M$!!! equals M.
To prove $A$ is dense in $M$, I am going to show the closure of $A$ in $M$!!! equals $M$.
My question however is this: Can I claim the closure of $A$ in $B$ equals the closure of $A$ in $M$? I think my claim is intuitively correct. however what do you think? if yes, how to prove this?
ps. By !!! I just mean this is the point of my question, where I am kinda confused. clearly not a mathematical symbol.

Comment: I just wanted to get attention to what I mean exactly as my question.

Comment: Take $M = [0, 1] \subseteq \Bbb{R}$, $A = (0, 1)$ and $B = [0, 1)$. Then the closure of $A$ in $B$ is $B$, which is not the same as the closure of $A$ in $M$, which is $[0, 1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $C\subseteq M$ is a closed subset of $M$ containing $A$. Then $C\cap B$ is closed in $B$ and contains $A$, hence contains the closure of $A$ in $B$. Since the closure of $A$ in $B$ equals $B$, we have $C\cap B\supseteq B$ which implies $C\supseteq B$. Since the closure of $B$ in $M$ is equal to $M$, we know the only closed subset containing $B$ is $M$. Therefore, $C=M$. Therefore, the closure of $A$ in $M$ is equal to $M$.

Comment: Thank you. everything seems clear to me except the last sentence. how did you conclude cl(A) in M = M? do you mean cl(A) in M = C and since you showed C = M the last sentence holds? then why?

Comment: There are several equivalent definitions of the closure of a subset, so I'm not sure which one you are using. The one that I had in mind is the following:

Comment: The closure of $A\subseteq M$ is the smallest closed subset which contains $A$. 

In other words, whenever there exists a closed subset $C\subseteq M$ such that $C\supseteq A$, this implies that $C\supseteq \mathrm{cl}(A)$.

In this case, we showed that the only closed subset of $M$ which contains $A$ is $M$ itself. Therefore, $M$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$.